# Cannot be instantiated

Tags: java, sprite

I've been trying to create a sprite to be used on our java game. Everything seems normal, i see no errors on my program but suddenly when it's to be run an error appeared that it Cannot be Instantiated. Can somebody tell me what's wrong with it?

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class TrueSprite
{
BufferedImage spriteSheet = ImageIO.read(new File("robin.png"));

int width = 240, height = 314, rows = 5 , columns = 5;

BufferedImage[] sprites = new BufferedImage[rows * columns];

public TrueSprite(int width, int height, int rows, int columns) throws IOException
{
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.rows = rows;
    this.columns = columns;

    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            sprites[(i * columns) + j ] = spriteSheet.getSubimage(i * width, j * height, width, height);
        }
    }

}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    g.drawImage(sprites[1], 100, 100, null);
}


}
```

here's the error:

```
load: really.sprite.TrueSprite.class can't be instantiated.
java.lang.InstantiationException: really.sprite.TrueSprite
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.createApplet(Unknown Source)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.runLoader(Unknown Source)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: If you need help with an exception or error, always post the full error/exception message and indicate which line(s) cause it.

Comment: done adding the errors.

Comment: Why does this class extend Applet? Does it have a constructor (if not an applet) or init method (if it is)? You've also got code sitting out in nether space, in neither a method nor a constructor, so this code shouldn't even compile.

Comment: A class that represents a sprite should **NOT** extend `Applet` (not sure why yours does)

Comment: oh sorry i copied the wrong code. >.<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have no constructor, which is essential for your class to be instantiated. Put this inside your class declaration:

```
public TrueSprite() {
    //code to run when your class is instantiated.
}
```

Now, this won't do anything special, but you can call it with:

```
TrueSprite sprite = new TrueSprite();
```

Additionally, your class needs to be cleaned up. Try putting your assignment code inside the constructor we just built, and the declaration to these variables outside of it:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class TrueSprite
{
    private final int width;
    private final int height;
    private final int rows;
    private final int cols;
    private BufferedImage bigImg;
    private BufferedImage[] sprites;

    public TrueSprite(int width, int height, int rows, int columns) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.rows = rows;
        this.cols = columns;
        this.bigImg = ImageIO.read(new File("robin.png"));
        this.sprites = new BufferedImage[rows * cols];

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                sprites[(i * cols) + j] = bigImg.getSubimage(j * width, i * height, width, height);    
            }
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawImage(sprites[1], 100, 100, null);
    }
}
```

Just make sure you pass in four valid arguments into your `TrueSprite` constructor to call it correctly:

```
TrueSprite sprite = new TrueSprite(200, 500, 20, 50);
```

Comment: The OP actually *has* a constructor. That prevents the compiler from generating the needed empty constructor.

Comment: When I began to answer, there was no constructor. See the edit log - the OP copied the wrong code.

Comment: i followed your instructions and a new set of errors appeared Exception in thread "main" java.awt.image.RasterFormatException: (x + width) is outside of Raster
 at sun.awt.image.ByteInterleavedRaster.createWritableChild(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.getSubimage(Unknown Source)
 at really.sprite.TrueSprite.<init>(TrueSprite.java:31)
 at really.sprite.Sprite.main(Sprite.java:13)

Comment: It seems like that's a separate issue altogether. Unless you can post code that is *directly related to the question you posted*, it looks like this fixes your problem. If you want to explore the realm of this new issue, please open a new question. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create a non param constructor like

public TrueSprite() throws IOException

Comment: this removed the newInstance error but still the program cant be run

Answer (score 0):

Your `BufferedImage[] sprites = new BufferedImage[rows * columns];` outside the constructor initialised the sprites array with a size of 5*5=25. If you created a TrueSprit with a higher row or column, e.g. `TrueSprite(100,100,100,100)`, the entries after sprites[24] will not be instantiated yet.

You should always place your initialisation inside the constructor. i.e.

```
private BufferedImage[] sprites;

public TrueSprite(int width, int height, int rows, int columns) throws IOException
{
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.rows = rows;
    this.columns = columns;
    this.sprites = new BufferedImage[rows * columns];

    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            sprites[(i * columns) + j ] = spriteSheet.getSubimage(i * width, j * height, width, height);
        }
    }
}
```

This will set the rows and columns to the correct value before creating your array with the values. Furthermore, you should have used a default constructor if you wanted to have default values. i.e.

```
public TrueSprite() throws IOException
{
    this.width = 240;
    this.height = 314;
    this.rows = 5;
    this.columns = 5;
    this.sprites = new BufferedImage[rows * columns];

    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            sprites[(i * columns) + j ] = spriteSheet.getSubimage(i * width, j * height, width, height);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried you code and this new set of errors appeared Exception in thread "main" java.awt.image.RasterFormatException: (y + height) is outside of Raster
 at sun.awt.image.ByteInterleavedRaster.createWritableChild(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.getSubimage(Unknown Source)
 at really.sprite.TrueSprite.<init>(TrueSprite.java:31)
 at really.sprite.Sprite.main(Sprite.java:13)